# Creating a Jump action

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I'm working in spritekit/IOS where I have a button that runs an action when it is clicked. The button works fine, but my action is terrible. On click I run this action.

```
actionMove=[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(300,300)duration:2.0];
```

Which then causes my sprite does a spinning flying kick too that location. I was needed a little help cause I tried replacing the y axis with

```
_sprite.position+10
```

But it gives me an error.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the action `moveByX:y:duration:`...

Sort of.

You can do this...

```
SKAction *rise = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:10 duration:1];
SKAction *fall = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-10 duration:1];
SKAction *jump = [SKAction sequence:@[rise, fall]];
```

Then you can run the `jump` action on your sprite.

This will move the sprite up by 10 points over 1 second and then down by 10 points over 1 second.

However, it will not look like a jump. It will not accelerate or anything.

If you are including something like a jump in your game then you would normally want to have some sort of collision detection with the floor and use forces to move your sprite instead of actions.

**Collision detection method**

**Sprite Kit Physics Engine**

There are two general ways you could do this. The easiest (although longest learning curve) is to use `SKPhysicsBody` and the built in physics engine in `SpriteKit`.

You would add a `SKPhysicsBody` to your character and a boundary SKPhysicsBody to the floor.

Then to make the character jump you would use something like...

```
[character.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 1)];
```

This will apply an immediate force to the character so it "jumps" in the air. Then with the physics engine you have built in gravity and so the character will start to slow down and fall until it hits the floor again.

There is a bit of setup for this (less than you would think) but once the setup is done the rest is VERY VERY VERY simple.

**Manually**

To do it manually is another case. This requires no setup but a LOT of maths. The way this works is to use the `update:` function and then each update cycle calculate what the velocity and position of the character is and to update the position accordingly.

You really don't want to do this though.

Make things really easy for yourself by adding `SKPhysicsBody` to the things that need to collide (the character and the floor) and then exploit the gravity and `applyImpulse`. It will make it much easier, it will perform faster and it will look a million times better :D

Comment: There are lots of Sprite Kit tutorials here http://www.raywenderlich.com/?s=sprite+kit&cof=FORID%3A10 I'm sure there is a physics one in there somewhere.

Comment: I already have a physics body on my sprite and gravity set up in my world. Just gonna try applying the impluse

Comment: Cool, I was hoping you would say that :D Good luck with the impulse. You'll have to try different values for the impulse. I don't know what will work to make the jump the right height etc...

Comment: @user3215538 remember to up vote and accept an answer if it helps you.

Comment: I did thanks :). But doesn't it have a time? Like how long you want the jump too last? (duration)

Comment: You can adjust the jump time by changing the impulse strength and the gravity strength. Bigger impulse with same gravity = higher jump. Same impulse with lower gravity = higher jump but slower fall so jump will last longer. You'll have to adjust the values you want for the game you are making. If you have a little jump and big jump then you could apply a second **force** when you detect that the button hasn't been released yet. This force could nudge your character a bit higher. etc...

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
CGPoint pos = _sprite.position;
pos.y = pos.y + 10;
_sprite.position = pos;
```

Comment: I'm conflicted because the other answer has such a great example and valuable information. However, if the person asking the question doesn't understand this answer first, I kind of question his ability to efficiently apply any of the concepts in the other answer besides via a cut/paste job and some fiddling. An understanding of what a CGPoint is and why his attempt didn't work, should precede any other solutions.

Comment: I do understand why my efforts weren't working based on his answer. However someone also noted that that method wasn't the way to accomplish that since my game uses physics so I just changed

Comment: I personally didn't understand the question that well. I thought that he was trying to update the position of the character with the update loop; which btw I do not think is a bad idea. You don't need to be a genius to do a simple interpolation. I personally think that physics is overkill for a little game like this (that we know nothing about; context is everything), and it can be glitchy. But don't believe me, read this blog post from the guy who wrote "Learn Cocos2D" http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/08/physics-engine-platformer-terrible-idea/

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use force (and physics) to move your player then using impulse will give you better results:

```
_sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, <value>);
```

The  above depends on a number of factors, including gravity value and the mass of the _sprite.physicsBody. Experimenting is the best way to figure out what works here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using physics you can use the followPath action and easing to get a somewhat realistic jumping effect (similar to cocos2d's jump to action). A simple example of how this can be implemented as a category method on SKAction:

```
+ (SKAction *)jumpWithStartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint height:(CGFloat)height {
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint:startPoint];
    CGPoint peak = CGPointMake(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, startPoint.y + height);
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint:endPoint controlPoint1:peak controlPoint2:peak];

    SKAction *jumpAction = [SKAction followPath:bezierPath.CGPath asOffset:NO orientToPath:NO duration:.5f];
    jumpAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseIn;
    return jumpAction;
}
```